# How do I link a html form with php, so that when clicking on a button for example, will return true?

Tags: javascript, php, html, button, social-networking

I am new to php, and I am wondering how do I create a button with php functioning in the background of the button? Sorry if what I am saying isn't very clear.

Also, in a social website, if that button will refresh the webpage with new information/text, how do I load the new info as well as deleting the old information?

Comment: Show some effort in code please

Answer (score 0):

1) Simply create a HTML form with method POST and action the page itself. When sending the data using the button PHP can analyse the POST request and do whatever you want.

2) You probably mean Web 2.0 . Websites like Facebook use JavaScript to make asyncronous Ajax calls to their backend and then replace the information on the screen with the new ones without the need to reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is specific to php. But here is a button in a php function that does something so it obtains other information.

```
<?php
function button(){
    if(isset($_GET['button'])) {
        // this information is shown when the get variable 'button' is set. The var $_GET['button'] is shown too in the case.
        echo "The button is clicked, it contains the following GET value: {$_GET['button']}";
    } else {
        // this information is only shown when there is no variable set in the URL, like 'button=clicked'
        echo "The button is not clicked yet.";
    }
    echo "<a href='?button=click'>Click on the button</a>";
}
// here the function is called.
button();
?>
```